# Counter in nested dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I have a large nested dictionary with the following structure:

```
data = {1:{u'hash1':u'127.0.0.1'},2:{u'hash2':u'0.0.0.2'},3:{u'hash3':u'0.0.0.2'}}
```

What I want is to count the hashes that correspond to unique IP's.
For example I would like to have the following result from the above dictionary:

```
IP              Addresses
127.0.0.1          1
0.0.0.2            2
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `collections.Counter`, like this

```
from collections import Counter
print Counter(data[k][hash_value] for k in data for hash_value in data[k])
# Counter({u'0.0.0.2': 2, u'127.0.0.1': 1})
```

Comment: Alternatively, `Counter(data[key].items()[0][1] for key in data)`

Comment: @timgeb I try to avoid using `items` as much as possible, as it is not subscriptable in Py 3.